# Dead store to local variable

Tags: android, onclicklistener

having a bug dead store to locaal variable in the following code please help.

here is my code-

```
detailImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RequisitionListDTO listDTO = new RequisitionListDTO();
                        listDTO = openFolderDetail(fileDesc);
                        setDocumentsList(listDTO, "LOAD");
                    }

                });
```

Comment: what do you mean by `dead store to locaal variable` ???

Comment: a local variable which is declared and not going to be used. waste of memory.

Comment: https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/findbugs:DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE?layout=false

Comment: i am a beginner.. please help if u can do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004309/how-to-deal-with-bug-dead-store-to-local-variable-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

```
RequisitionListDTO listDTO = new RequisitionListDTO();
```

and then

```
listDTO = openFolderDetail(fileDesc);
```

You haven't mentioned where you get this warning. But the first initialization is needless because you are overwriting it immediately. Better write this directly:

```
RequisitionListDTO listDTO = openFolderDetail(fileDesc);
```

Comment: @Sangeeta Or you may use i.e. `setDocumentsList(openFolderDetail(fileDesc), "LOAD");`